# How to remove ^M (CRLF) from w file sent from Windows to linux FTP server in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, ftp, ascii, newline

I'm sending a comma delimited file (in ASCII) via Net::FTP in perl (generated on Windows) to a linux based FTP account. The issue is that my file on the linux side has ^M at the end of each line. I know I can remove these by calling a 
dos2unix" command on that file but how do I remove ^M on the windows side so that I send a correct file in the first place.

I tried doing the below but that doesn't affect the file on the linux side.

```
$content =~ s/^M//g;
```

Comment: I tried both $ftp->ascii and $ftp->binary doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Did you try it on Windows side?

Comment: Yes, all of these solutions I try to apply in the perl code on windows side when the actual file is being created and then sent to the linux FTP.

Comment: Stumped. Try using another FTP client to upload? Try using another FTP server on Unix end? This is exactly what ascii() is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you had "^","M", then s/\^M//g would work. ("^" is special in regex patterns.) If you had a CR, then s/\r\n/\n/g (or just s/\r//g) would work.

If neither work, please provide a portion of "od -c" of your data file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing the file:

```
open my $fh, '>:raw', $file or die "could not open $file: $!\n";
```

See `perldoc -f binmode`.

Comment: So I tied doing open (FH, '>:raw', $file) but I still get ^M on the linux side